# iOS - Issue with displaying battery status

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to display battery percentage with UILabel , but the result is nonsense ! here is my code :

```
UIDevice *myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    [myDevice setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
    int i=[myDevice batteryState];
    _battery.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i];
```

the labels shows number 2 !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code to get battery level

```
UIDevice *myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
[myDevice setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
float batteryLevel = [myDevice batteryLevel];
_battery.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",batteryLevel*100];
```

`[myDevice batteryLevel];` will give you the battery between 0.0 (empty) and 1.0 (100% charged)

Hope it helps..

Comment: worth noting that 'setBatteryMonitoringEnabled' method isn't thread safe, as mentioned in https://github.com/jszumski/uidevice-threading-crash, http://openradar.appspot.com/13941890, https://twitter.com/cheesemaker/status/517373206748205056.

Answer (score 1):

`iPhone OS` provides two type of battery monitoring events, one for when the state changes (*e.g., charging, unplugged, full charged*) and one that updates when the battery’s charge level changes. As was the case with proximity monitoring, you register callbacks to receive notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification" object:device];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification" object:device];
```

ALso refer this [link.](http://iosdevelopertips.com/device/display-battery-state-and-level-of-charge.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
[myDevice batteryState];//return is a variable of UIDeviceBatteryState
```

the labels shows number 2 means"UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging,    // plugged in, less than 100%",if you want to display battery percentage. The code in the first answer will help you.