# Battery Usage - IOS

Tags: ios, batterylevel

I want to show battery usage of the app on the status bar of the app. It uses GPS, so GPS signal and details of battery usage by app would be useful for the users about the battery drain.

Is there a way to get the battery usage from the device? and to show only the amount of battery drained by *my app* alone. On instruments it shows the graph over the time.

I want to show battery usage in numerical format, not a graph.

Comment: in a GPS-related app, I would be scared if I saw how much battery it drains :) nice idea though

Answer (score 4):

Use below code to get battery level

```
UIDevice *myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
[myDevice setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
float batteryLevel = [myDevice batteryLevel];
_battery.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",batteryLevel*100];
[myDevice batteryLevel];
```

will give you the battery between 0.0 (empty) and 1.0 (100% charged)

[iOS - Issue with displaying battery status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700403/ios-issue-with-displaying-battery-status)

Comment: Thanks for you reply but this shows the current battery level but I wanna show amount of battery just MY APP alone drained. Sorry if my earlier question was not clear about what am looking for.....

Comment: I changed my question to what am exactly I need. Thank U so much for answering my first query. Now I need to calculate on the battery usage of the app alone. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: At the time of app start get the battery status and store it then in your app, after some intervals take the battery status, subtract it from the starting status and display to the user. this way you can show updated battery status to the user continuously.

Comment: the difference of the battery would show how much your app has consumed the battery. i hope you got my point.

Comment: This is what I was thinking but the lock here is, we can't be sure that only our app is running on the user device. What if heavy battery draining games running simultaneously with our app. We then end up showing battery drained by both (or few more running) apps. This is now not gonna show our app battery usage alone right?

Comment: buddy you cant run 2 apps at once on an iphone :)

Comment: This is for iOS 5 and above and so we can run multiple apps simultaneously.

Comment: This is for iOS 5 and above and so we can run multiple apps simultaneously. Wherein when one app is on foreground. Other apps can run in the background

Comment: the apps in background dont take that much battery. so as for your app when its in foreground, it is the major utilizer of the battery.

Answer (score 0):

From command line we can get the battery details of iOS phones using [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) tools.

Inside the tools use the command:

```
./ideviceinfo -q com.apple.mobile.battery
```

It will return something like:

BatteryCurrentCapacity: 30
BatteryIsCharging: true
ExternalChargeCapable: true
ExternalConnected: true
FullyCharged: false
GasGaugeCapability: true

Comment: I know to get the battery level. But What am looking for is, I wanted to know ONLY the amount of Power consumed by MY APP ALONE.

Comment: In automated runs that we have, we add a call before and after the test suite and calculate the difference to understand the consumed battery level. I am not sure if you can get the consumed battery of that particular app.

Comment: Hi @Manoj could please let me know how do you get battery level. I need it

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BatteryStatus/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008812