# Getting battery usage information for other iOS apps

Tags: ios, battery

[image: Battery Usage]

I want to show these other applications' Battery Usage percentage values from my own application. Can I do that?

Comment: This should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807295/how-to-get-real-time-battery-level-on-ios

Comment: possible duplicate of [Battery Usage - IOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396928/battery-usage-ios)

Comment: There is no public method to get _per application_. Reference https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html BTW, what's your usecase?

Comment: Generally, if your question for iOS ends with "for other applications" the answer is "it's not possible"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can monitor the current battery percentage using UIDevice. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html

Unfortunately there is no way to tell which applications are draining the battery.